# What is the meaning of のだと in this context?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

> これが学習者にとっては妙な**のだと**気付くには慣れが必要かもしれませんが

What does のだとmean here ?

Comment: Please, do not use parenthesis and bold to highlight the **whole** sentence. Just type > at the beginning to make it a quote, you don't need neither () nor ** ** wrapping the whole sentence.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29799/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15057/9831